# After using Sort_values() function my dataframe become empty and show TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[In my data frame I have this data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QD9cq.png)

```
df_first_year = df['FIRST_YEAR']
df_last_year = df['LAST_YEAR']
df_span = df['span']
```

I want to use span column as  bin in histogram. So, when I run this part of code (below). It shows error (ValueError: `bins` must increase monotonically, when an array)

```
plt.hist(df_first_year, bins=df_span, edgecolor='black')
plt.legend()
```

Thats why I tried to sort the dataframe by span column. Like this

```
df = df.sort_values(by=["span"], inplace=True)
```

After running this part of code. When I want to see my dataframes data, it
[shows None. I think that means there is no data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfU82.png)

Is there any another option or what I have done wrong in my simple code !!!!!

Comment: If you use `inplace=True`, the function returns None.  Don't assign the result back to df.

Comment: ok...thanks...so, should I store it into another variable

Comment: No.  `inplace=True` means the function modifies the original df instead of returning a new df .  You don't need to assign anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem.

```
df = df.sort_values(by=["span"], inplace=True)
```

**Reason**: Inplace means you're setting reflect changes to dataframe as true, which *does not return any values*.

If you're using `inplace` argument for the `sort_values` function, use it as either

```
df.sort_values(by=["span"], inplace=True)
```

OR

```
df = df.sort_values(by=["span"], inplace=False)
```

Comment: thank you, I was getting stuck because of another bug, did a lot of change and nothing was working, until I get your inplace explanation